# Spring jsp template to herritate the design

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am looking for an easy way to heritate the design (navigation, global imports and so on) from a kinda template in spring.

Is there any possibillity for this?

Comment: Look at Sitemesh, Tiles and potentially other template engines.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your reply. Is there no build in support in Spring?

Comment: AFAIK, no. There's nothing in the reference documentation, except a chapter about tiles.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much, in my case I will have 4 jsps with duplicated design entries. So I think the effort in implementing any template engine would be way to much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, no more answers will be added here, it seems in the moment there are no Template Engines build in in Spring. Here is a incomplete list of Template Engines:
[Template List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29#Comparison)